# Fetch a particular content from a row using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

how can a fetch a particular content from a row in which the row contents product name,barcode,quantity and buy price.I am to delete the particular row by using this jquery

```
  $('#Delete').live('click',function(row) {
  $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).addClass("selected");
  /**/
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
 $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlight');
$('tr').click(function(){$(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);});
var button = $(this);
var ok=confirm("You really want to delete?");

if(ok)
{   
 $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // remove row

    }
return false; // prevents default behavior
 });
```

Comment: The deleting row part is working all right, I guess? So what "particular content from a row" you want to fetch?

Comment: yup deleting row is working perfectly ..... i just need to fetch a content like barcode before its been deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IM using this function for that:

```
function todoDelete(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/todo/delete/' + id,
        success: function() {
            $('#update_' + id).css('backgroundColor', '#ff6666');
            $('#update_' + id).fadeOut(250);
        }
    });
}
```

But you can modifie as that:

```
$('a.delete').click(function(link){
    var row = $(link).parent('tr');
    var id = row.children('td.id').html(); // append id class, there is your id
    $.ajax({
        url: '/delete/' + id,
        success: function() {
            row.css('backgroundColor', '#ff6666');
            row.fadeOut(250);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Apply to your needs that code. Fetching: `$(link).parent('tr').children('td.barcode').html()`, if it returns null, try full request, not over vars. And append barcode class to each td element.